# How to use a C# enumeration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, enums

I have a enum in my C# code and i want to get names from enum in my jQuery validate rules.

**Enum:**

```
public enum EnumItemField
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
}
```

**Validate:**

```
function updateFieldStatus() {
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#IntegrationService").validate({
    rules: {
        //Set range of Start
        "config.EnumFormat[Zero].Start": {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            range: [1, 200]
        },
        "config.EnumFormat[One].Start": {
            required: true,
            digits: true,        
            range: [1, 200]
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        MsgBoxService.show({
            //setId: "saveload",
            //objectId: "asrun"
        });
    },
});
```

This really works, but I want make something like this:

```
"config.EnumFormat[" + item + "].Start": {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    range: [1, 200]
}
```

In C# I can get names in this way:

```
foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumItemField)))
```

How can I make it in javascript? Thanks for advice!

Comment: Hi str_str, kindly check out my answer and let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: I have no idea why your answer don't work

Comment: var is not identified, maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Please upload a screenshot! This is crazy. Doesn't look like a JavaScript error. Are you sure this is JavaScript you need?

Comment: Magic, problem fixed. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the same thing as a JavaScript Object.

```
EnumItemField = {
    "Zero": 0,
    "One": 1,
    "Two": 2,
    "Three": 3,
    "Four": 4,
    "Five": 5
}
```

Please don't forget to remove the last `,` comma.

You can use the values like:

```
EnumItemField.Zero     // 0
EnumItemField["Zero"]  // 0
```

Iteration? No problem:

```
for (var item in EnumItemField) {
  item;                // Zero
  EnumItemField[item]; // 0
}
```

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yeah, sure. `:)`